# Jest encountered an unexpected token #3746

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

error when try run test

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its
> dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not
> configured to support such syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform
> your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
>
> Here's what you can do:  • If you are trying to use ECMAScript
> Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to
> enable it.  • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see
> https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript  • To have
> some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a
> custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.  • If you need a
> custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.  •
> If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets)
> you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
>
> You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the
> docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration For information about
> custom transformations, see:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
>
> Details:
>
> D:@workspace\monotest\packages\one\build\index.js:1
> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import
> { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'; Additional context No response

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late but for future reference here's what you can do.

In your `jest.config.(js|ts)` file you can

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^uuid$': require.resolve('uuid'),
},
```